# raster to polygon conversion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-2.7

I 'm trying to automate the conversion of raster to polygon and the rasters files are in "TIF" format which is a "unsigned integer". I have the code below. However, I 'm getting an error while executing it. Could you have some suggestion please?

Code:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#To overwrite output
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/Subhasis/Test/Neshanic_Python/extract"

outws="C:/Subhasis/Test/Neshanic_Python/extract/clip/"

#checkout ArcGIS spatial analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

inraster = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")

for i in inraster:
    filename=os.path.splitext(i)[0]
    outPolygons= outws + str(filename) + '.shape'
    field = "VALUE"
    arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(inraster, outPolygons, "NO_SIMPLIFY", field)
```

> Error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Subhasis\Test\Neshanic_Python\extract\Clip.py", line 23, in
>   
>       arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(inraster, outPolygons, "NO_SIMPLIFY", field)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 241, in
>   RasterToPolygon raise e

Comment: @artwork21. Thank you very much for editing my post! Do I need any software for this editing? if yes where do I get it?

Comment: Shapefiles don't have the extension ".shape"; it's `.shp`

Comment: also the formatting help page is here.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: FYI, you also don't need to check out the spatial analyst extension to convert raster to polygons.  It's core ArcGIS.

Answer (score 3):

For this line:

```
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(inraster, outPolygons, "NO_SIMPLIFY", field)
```

You are inserting a list not an individual raster file, trying changing it to:

```
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(i, outPolygons, "NO_SIMPLIFY", field)
```

Comment: Yes, I did that stupid mistake.Thank you very much It worked! Another topic, How do I post my question so that you don't have to edit it? If I need anything to install,Where do i get it? Thank you!

Comment: There should be text called edit under the question tags that you can click on to edit it.

Comment: good morning! Sorry to bother you. I may sound stupid, I was looking for the text "edit" to edit my code. But I didn't get it. I was wondering  do I need to install something as I didn't see anything under "question tab". Thank you!