# Automate convert floating point raster files (Tif extension) to polygon

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I'm trying to automate the conversion of raster to polygon and the raster files are in "TIF" format which is a "floating point". I copy the code below from [raster to polygon conversion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108655)
so it needs some changes because of "unsigned integer" and ...that I don't know.

How can I correct this code?

I'm getting an error while executing it.

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
> line 18, in  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Code

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#To overwrite output
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Set environment settings
env.workspace = "K:\1400-10-20"

outws="K:\1400-10-20\m"

#checkout ArcGIS spatial analyst extension license
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

inraster = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")

for i in inraster:
    filename=os.path.splitext(i)[0]
    outPolygons= outws + str(filename) + '.shape'
    field = "VALUE"
    arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(i, outPolygons, "NO_SIMPLIFY", field)
```

Comment: Edit and remove the ...

Answer (score 1):

As the error shows "Nonetype", it means that your variable "inraster" is empty. It is because of the incorrect way of writing the folder paths in your code. The variables where you are setting the workspace and other paths should be written with either double backslash ("\\") or single forward-slash ("/").

For example in your code:

```
env.workspace = "K:\1400-10-20"
outws="K:\1400-10-20\m"
```

must be replaced with

```
 env.workspace = "K:/1400-10-20"
 outws="K:/1400-10-20/m"
```

or

```
env.workspace = "K:\\1400-10-20"
outws="K:\\1400-10-20\\m"
```

Comment: hi first of all i appreciate your consideration i did what you mentioned  but  there is another problem

Comment: Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 21, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 337, in RasterToPolygon     raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000864: Input raster: The input is not within the defined domain. ERROR 000367: Invalid GP data type Failed to execute

Comment: i think that the  ERROR 000864 is related to "float" format type  i have to change all my float raster files  to integer then convert  to polygon  could you please tell me how can i do it automitically and with python.thank you so much

Comment: Yes, you are right. Integer raster is required to run the required tool. Please go through the below given link, it will help you to resolve your issue. Accordingly, you can write a code to automate that task.
https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012554